# rails jquery formtastic partial => undefined method 'inputs'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, partial, formtastic

I'm trying to update the values of a select statement when another field is changed.

This is my code:

Form (_form.html):

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:projects,@projectmilestone], :remote => true  do |form| %>

    <%= form.semantic_errors :state %>
    <%= form.inputs do %>
      <%= form.input :name, :as => :string%>
      <%= form.input :description, :as => :text%>
      <%= form.input :department_id, :as => :select, :collection => Department.all, :wrapper_html => { :class => "submittable" }%>
      <%= form.input :custom, :as => :hidden%>
      <%= form.input :projectcapstone_id , :as => :hidden %>
      <div id="stakeholders">
        <%=render :partial => "stakeholders_form", :locals => { :form => form }%>
      </div>
      <%= form.input :statusweight, :as => :numeric%>
      <%= form.input :ratingweight, :as => :numeric%>


    <%  end %>

    <%= form.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>
```

partial with field to be updated:

```
<% unless @projectmilestone.department_id.nil? %>
  <% form.inputs :partial do %>
    <%= form.input :user_id , :as => :select, :collection => @users %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

jQuery function in my application.js file:

```
$('.submittable').live('change', function() {
$(this).parents('form:first').submit();
return false;
});
```

Controller:

```
  def update
    @projectmilestone = Projectmilestone.find(params[:id])
    @users= User.where("department_id = ?",@projectmilestone.department_id) unless @projectmilestone.department_id.nil?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @projectmilestone.update_attributes(params[:projectmilestone])
        format.js {render :layout => false}
      end
    end
  end
```

update.js.erb file in my views:

```
$('#projectmilestone_department_id').css("color","red");
$("#stakeholders").replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "stakeholders_form", :locals => { :form => form } ) %>");
```

The partial loads fine at first page load but when loaded through the javascript, I get following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `inputs' for #<String:0x00000117e81940>):
    1: <% unless @projectmilestone.department_id.nil? %>
    2:   <% form.inputs :partial do %>
    3:     <%= form.input :user_id , :as => :select, :collection => @users %>
    4:   <% end %>
    5: <% end %>
  app/views/projects/projectmilestones/_stakeholders_form.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_projects_projectmilestones__stakeholders_form_html_erb__1391421669166525649_2348024640__1321038554949321784'
  app/views/projects/projectmilestones/update.js.erb:4:in `_app_views_projects_projectmilestones_update_js_erb__638343879728010384_2348034340_1083018837200874056'
  app/controllers/projects/projectmilestones_controller.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in update'
  app/controllers/projects/projectmilestones_controller.rb:86:in `update'
```

The javascript UJS loop works ok too, as the css is changed to red when I change the department_id field.

I guess the error has something to do with the locals but i don't know what.

Please help!!!

Thx,

Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the update.js.erb you don't have a `form` object so this will fail.

Perhaps you could look at the HTML that the partial churns out then rewrite it so that takes `@projectmilestone` and `@users` as parameters.

Your update method has both of these parameters available so should work.